# CONCAT in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I don't know if I should use comma (,) or "||" as separator in CONCAT function for Oracle SQL.
This one works:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, last_name) as name
FROM TABLE1
```

However, none of these below works out (I need to put a space between first_name and last_name, or to extract the initial letter from last_name and wrap this letter with parenthesis):

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name || last_name) as name
FROM TABLE1

SELECT CONCAT(first_name || ' ' || last_name) as name 
FROM TABLE1

SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as name 
FROM TABLE1

SELECT CONCAT(first_name, '(', UPPER(STR(last_name, 1,1)), ')') as name 
FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: I'd use `||`, as it's standard SQL - and more flexible. Oracle's concat() function only takes 2 arguments.

Comment: For oracle you can do `SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(first_name, ' '), last_name) as name
FROM TABLE1`

Comment: Got it. If I have 4+ things to concat, is there any more efficient way to concat? Like the bottom one in the above question. Otherwise, I will have to use concat many times. Thanks!!

Comment: Oracle is being awkward by only allowing 2 comma-separated arguments in a CONCAT. So ignore CONCAT and just double-pipe the fields and strings.

Comment: @SilverSpringbb 'I' || ' am' || ' using' || ' 3 double-pipes'

Answer (score 0):

Using double-pipe (||) instead of CONCAT in Oracle SQL is a more efficient way to go. Thanks to the comments that folks provided in here.

```
SELECT (first_name || ' ' || last_name)as name
FROM Table1;
```

Output:

```
John Smith
```

I also fixed the last script in the above question. Somehow it needs two right parentheses before "as name".

```
SELECT first_name || '(' || UPPER(SUBSTR(last_name, 1,1)) || ')')) as name, first_name, last_name 
FROM TABLE1
```

Output:

```
John(S) John Smith
```